# How to configure Websphere 8.5 to 'call' all jmv endpoint?

Tags: caching, jvm, websphere

I need a way to invoke each jvm endpoint of a cluster on Websphere in order to call the jvm to refresh the cache.
If I have the endpoint, I'm not sure in which jvm the request is going to be handled. The ideal thing would be to call every jvm endpoint to force them to refresh.
Is there any way I can do this on Websphere?
Or maybe having a different port for each jvm.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit. What do you mean by calling a jvm, what is the mode of invocation?

Comment: I guess you mean you need to hit your application so the cache can be refreshed?  Why not use something like a [Timer Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) to refresh the cache?